# With reveal.js, how can I make slides change upon completion of embedded media?

Tags: javascript, css, html, presentation, reveal.js

I am using reveal.js to make a relatively simple slideshow. I am not using basement levels, fragments, etc. Just several slides with a few bit of text and images, with audio on some slides, and video on others.

I'd really like to have the slide move on to the next upon the completion of the media. I would like it to feel as though there was someone changing slides as they would do giving this presentation in a live setting.

There is a variety of run times, some are only 0:15 and some are up to 4 minutes.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

In general, bind a listener to the completion event and advance the slide.

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  Reveal.next()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`audio-slideshow` plugin](https://github.com/rajgoel/reveal.js-plugins) does exactly what you are looking for.